# get selector of jsonp when it loaded?

Tags: javascript, json, blogspot

i've been code something can get blogspot json data with native javascript, but i want to add a post slider but when i call a variable point to the class of posts class, it return

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined
>   Here the slider Code

```js
var item = document.querySelectorAll(".featured .item"),
  slideLeft = document.getElementById("slideLeft"),
  slideRight = document.getElementById("slideRight"),
  current = 0;

function reset() {
  for (var i in item) {
    if (item[i].classList.contains("current")) {
      item[i].classList.remove = "current"
    }
  }
}

function startSlide() {
  reset();
  item[0].classList.add("current");
}

function sLeft() {
  reset();
  item[current - 1].classList.add("current");
  current--;
}

function sRight() {
  reset();
  item[current + 1].classList.add("current");
  current++;
}
slideLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = item.length;
  }
  sLeft()
})
slideRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === item.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  sRight()
})
startSlide()
```

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/z5kgd7pe/3/) is my jsfiddle that I created.

Please give me a way to add the slide in json post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix that error by wrapping your `//handle slider` code in a function and calling it when the JSONP response comes back. [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wg0k5m6u/3/)

Right now your are executing `var item = document.querySelectorAll(".featured .item")` before the response comes back and the HTML does not exist at this point which means `item` is an empty node list.

You are getting

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined"

because in `reset()` you loop through the **properties** of the returned empty node list (not necessarily only the nodes you expected) in your case an inherited property comes through the loop- the `length` property and that does not have a `classList` property so that is why `item[i].classList.contains("current")` would return that error.

Bonus info: To prevent looping through properties in the objects prototype chain you can include a check for [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) like so:

```
for (var i in item) {
  // if the item object does not have this property as its own 
  // (for example its an inherited property) then skip this property.
  if (!item.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    continue;
  }
  ....
}
```